# Making everything Invisible

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

Anyone know how I can make everything in my body invisible in one line of code. I am trying to seem like the page is "deleted" but really everything is still there. This is in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
document.body.style.visibility = "hidden";  // dimensions remain
```

or

```
document.body.style.opacity = "0";          // all functionalities remain
```

I have no idea why you would need this.

Comment: Lol, well, I guess you will have to find out. (thanks btw)

Comment: Nvm just reloaded the page

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.display = "none";
```

This will remove everything on-page, as if it's not even there.  Visibility/Opacity will disable elements from view, but they'll technically still have heights and widths.